# How to get favorites star

Tags: android, user-interface, icons

I would like to add a favorites star like the one in the contacts list on android.  Is there any way we can get that star or will I have to write my own?  I can't seem to find any standard GUI Elements from android other than the options menu icons.  Are there any more that I have not found?

Look at the one the right next to George Anderson.  When you click it it turns yellow.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mail2web.com](https://mail2web.com/services-data/images/android/contacts-on-android.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some standard android images are available from the android sdk, which you can either browse on your computer on online [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/res/res;hb=HEAD). (As CommonsWare said).

I also find [this website](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/) super handy, as it shows me what each image looks like and tells me the name of the image so I can find it in the android sdk.

Comment: That website with all the images is awesome.  Thanks

Comment: Great info, but I wonder why on earth the author used a *frame* on that page. Nothing but annoying.

Comment: As of Aug 2015, both those links are dead.

Answer (score 25):

The source code to the Contacts application is [available online](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=tree), since Android is open source.

Some poking around in there will lead you to the `contact_header.xml` file, found in your SDK installation. It indicates that the star is implemented via a `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_star"
        style="?android:attr/starStyle" />
```

That, in turn, routes you to an entry in a theme:

```
<item name="starStyle">@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.Star</item>
```

which in turn resolves to:

```
<style name="Widget.CompoundButton.Star">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_star_label_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">@android:drawable/btn_star</item>
</style>
```

So, use those images with a `CheckBox`, and you should get the same behavior. Those images are also available in your SDK installation.

Answer (score 1):

@android:drawable/btn_star (this one turns yellow)

@android:drawable/star_off

and variations on those (big, on, off)